# Replacing Swift Storyboard with New, Imported Storyboard

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard

Having completed the functionality in code, my app required a full redevelopment of the original interface design. That was done by another team member, in a separate project.

It seems obvious that importing the new design as a storyboard file and using that is the next step. The original storyboard has a number of segues, I'd like to just replace the UI contents of that with the contents of the new storyboard (and then reconnect everything).

I'm not sure how to do this. What's the best method?

Comment: I think you might want to just reconnect the segues (I can't figure out how to replace the main view of a View Controller, and if you paste in the subviews, you lose most constraints)